# How to show "®" read from text file in assets directory?

Tags: android, special-characters, textview, symbols, android-assets

Does anybody know the best way to show the "®" symbol when read from a text file in the assets directory? I've tried replacing the "®" symbol with &® or ® or \u00AE, but none of these work.

Is the only solution to define it as html?

Here's the code I'm using to read the text file from assets:

```
    mTextViewTermsConditions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_terms_conditions);

    StringBuffer stringBufferEula = new StringBuffer();

    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("eula");

        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = f.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            Logger.d(line);

            stringBufferEula.append(line);

            line = f.readLine();
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Logger.e(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mTextViewTermsConditions.setText(stringBufferEula);
```

Comment: Make sure that the encoding of the text file is UTF-8. What is printing instead of the ® symbol?

Comment: This garbage symbol shows instead of "®": �

I encoded as UTF-8 and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @TedHopp You should add that as an answer so that the OP can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an encoding problem. Make sure that your asset file is stored with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Answer thanks to Ted Hopp above:
Make sure that the text file is encoded UTF-8.